# Can I have multiple Triggers in Cruise Control?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

At the moment I have

> ```
> <!-- Builds Every 300 seconds the condition is set to if a modification exists -->
> <triggers>
>   <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="300" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
> </triggers>
> ```

and I'm just wondering can you have multiple triggers inside the ccnet.config and can you set it so you only execute certain parts e.g, if a modification changes on the svn client, run one part of the config. and every night at 12 o'clock force a nighty build and deploy an msbuild to Octopus or does the whole ccnet config run when a build condition is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MultiTrigger, which basically groups several triggers, as what you described, see here:
http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Multi_Trigger